# How to make a query or macro to alter another table

Tags: ms-access

I have a table in access 2007 that has a list of students and their total unit score.

I have a query that finds all students with unit values totalled less than 17 (if you have less than 17 points you cannot graduate).

I also have a query that finds all students with unit values totalled more than 17 (they can graduate).

How would I go about adding another column to the original table that says whether they will graduate?

Basically I have this:

```
 ______|Student|___|Points|
        Johnny      18    
        Markus      5
```

And basically I want this:

```
 ______|Student|___|Points|___|Graduation Status|______
        Johnny      18         Y
        Markus      5          N
```

How can I achieve the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two queries:

1. Adds a column
2. Updates the column with Y or N

Query to add a column

```
alter table table_name 
add column gradution_status text
```

Query to update the newly added column with Y or N

```
update table_name 
set graduation_status = IIF (points < 17, "N", "Y")
```

If you accidentally ran both queries two times, the first will inform you that there is already a field existing in the table. The query will just stop there, so no harm will be done. The 2nd query will re-update `graduation_status` field. No harm there as well.

If you were using Office 2010, you could create a column as a calculated field with formula `IIF(points < 17, "N", "Y")`